# Rails 3/Paperclip: How to extract path as string for image processing? (NOT ImageMagick!)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, paperclip

I'm running a web app that uploads images through paperclip, then performs image processing on them in an opencv-backed ruby extension gem, which requires a string path to run.  The code I've been using is as follows:

```
imageFiles # => Array of ActiveRecord objects with attached paperclip files ('image')
filenames = Array.new()
imageFiles.each{ |imFile|
    filenames.push( imFile.image.path )
}
imgproc = ImageProcessor.new # => extension
imgproc.process( filenames )
```

This gives me the following error:

```
can't convert Paperclip::Attachment into String
```

If I push:

```
imFile.image.file_name
```

Instead, my error becomes:

```
undefined method `file_name' for /xxx/xxx/xxx/000/000/062/original/img.jpg?1340296339:Paperclip::Attachment
```

Am I on the right path, or is there a step I'm missing?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I remember having this same problem/question, I'll check it out, but I don't have my environment here. Are all your configuration paramaters set? Try to access the item's 'path' attribute directly (like read_attribute(:path))

Comment: I can access the path.  I've even tried extracting the filename, using FileUtil to make a copy, and delete the original.  Still gives me the same error.

Comment: I think you are not accesing the path correctly for some misconfiguration on Paperclip, but still don't know. I'm assuming ImageProcessor.process needs the asset's path, right?

Check what imFile.image.path.class is, because it's returning an Attachment. Try imFile.image.path(:default). Doing imFile.image.to_s should return the path's string also.

Comment: I definitely tried all of those.  No matter what, it still saw attachment.  I actually abandoned paperclip and now I'm working with Carrierwave, instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that earlier I was pushing an image into the array of filenames instead of the files themselves, one of the dangers of ducktyped languages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how opencv-backed works but you can try to push only the image object.

```
filenames.push( imFile.image )
```

Comment: OpenCV takes a string filename (with or without path, so long as it can be find), and doing imFile.image results in the can't convert error above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error trying to send a file.  In my case, I simply had to convert the object to a string.

```
    file = @my_object.my_document
    path = open(file.to_s)
    send_file(path,
       :type => "application/pdf",
       :disposition => 'inline', :filename => "My File")
```